# What artifical intelligence theory is most likely to lead to intelligent machines?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network

I am currently reading *On Intelligence* by Jeff Hawkins. His memory-prediction framework is very thought provoking and is a promising explanation as to what intelligence may be. Are there any other theories, along similar lines, that attempt to provide an all encompasing theory of intelligence?

Comment: You might want to change the title. To me, the current title suggest a question that would get closed for being opinion, but the question itself seems legitimate.

Comment: An interesting question, but probably too broad and unspecific to be answered here. Let's see whether this gets any good answers or will be closed.

Comment: @peachykeen: Although an interesting question, it is not exactly in the spirit of the site (ie: programming based).  Now, if he had a theory and was turning it into code and needed some help, that would be an altogether different thing.

Comment: @Chris: from the last sentence, it seems he's interested in what theories are out there that are similar to the one referenced. Seems like it could be programming related, or maybe not.

Comment: @peachykeen: Good point I shall change the title to just asking about theories. @Chris: The reason Im asking this is to attempt an implementation of the best theory

Comment: Sorry Im a newbie. What exactly was wrong with this post? I thought the question was quite specific. What promising theories are there that explain intelligence.

Comment: @Eldorado: It's still an overly broad question and not something that can be simply answered, and certainly not answered with code.  Quite frankly, the answer itself might be enough to fill a book with the relative merits of the various approaches out there.  You might start with this wikipedia article and go from there in your research: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence

Comment: @Chris Lively: +1 for raising the "can it be answered with code?" point.

Comment: @Chris: I appreciate you taking the time to reply. The memory-prediction framework has many implementations as can be seen from its wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-prediction_theory One in particular of interest is http://sourceforge.net/projects/neocortex/ I was hoping to discover competing theories from this post.

Comment: @Eldorado: You're getting closer to something the community might consider a real question for this forum.  If you are trying to find an implementation of particular theories, ask for that.  If you are asking about the theories themselves, unfortunately that belongs elsewhere.  Bear in mind that there are probably very few people on this site that could even hazard a guess much less give a breakdown of competing theories.  I'd wager to say that most people who even tried to answer would probably just take your words and google for answers.

Comment: The SO thought police strike again, doing their best to shut down legitimate Q&A-style discussions. This site really is much more of a police state tailored to the limited needs of a very small band of conventional, unimaginative programmers than it is a place for open questions and answers.  Please don't bother to mention the FAQ; this place will live or die by its ability to meet the needs of the broader community, not the limited notions of the jackboots who wrote the FAQ guidelines.  SO can and will be replaced eventually if it doesn't drop its police-state mentality.